# Turn/rebuke undead vs animate dead spell

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, undead

If I animate undead by Animate Dead spell, can some evil cleric command them?

Comment: Hello Anthony, and welcome to RPG.SE. I suggest you take the [tour] to learn a bit more about our community. While your question in itself is ok, it could help if you give us a few more details on the situation.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes.

There is nothing special about Undead created by the Animate Dead spell, they will react to effects that target Undead the same way any other Undead does. That means they can be rebuked, commanded, turned, controlled, or have any other effect applied to them that targets Undead creatures.